# How to increase memory size for JVM beyond 1gb

Tags: java, memory, jvm, jvm-arguments

When I try to set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` values more than 1gb, I am getting an error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM

My pc has 8GB of RAM.

I need to hold and manipulate a huge amount of data in memory.

Comment: How you are do that? Show the line

Comment: What OS? What JVM? What arguments?

Comment: windows 7 64 bit, jvm 32 bit

Comment: Why not use a 64-bit jvm?

Comment: Uhwhat? A 32bit JVM on a 64bit OS? Scrap that. Get a 64bit JVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 32-bit JVM can have a maximum heap size of at most 4GB - in some systems it's less due to various technical reasons (such as the need for contiguous memory). Try using a 64-bit version, assuming you're on a 64-bit machine.

The reason for this is that the maximum number of addresses that you can point to with 32 bits is 2^32, which is 4GB. This theoretical maximum can never really be accessed by the user as it is needed by the JVM for `Klass` files (the internal representation of your code) and other stuff.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os).

Comment: he was not asking about >4GB he was asking about >1GB

Comment: The JVM heap size is less than 2^32, you have to account for thread stacks, permgen, etc etc

Comment: i am using 32bit jvm and cant increase beyond 1gb

Comment: What sizes have you tried? As fge said there are many reasons the maximum heap size is less than the theoretical maximum of 4GB.

Comment: In practice on Windows, the 32-bit JVM will not go beyond 1G ish.

Comment: What Andrew Finnell said - it's due to the need for contiguous memory. Just use a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457514/understanding-max-jvm-heap-size-32bit-vs-64bit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 64 bit os than the real solution is adding -d64 to force it to run in 64 bits and therefore allocate the 4GBs.

Answer (score 0):

i would definitely suggest you to go thru article

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory.html

Apart from Ram, xmx paramters also depends on parameters like os,jvm bit etc.

Also would suggest you to ahve statistics  to determine how much free memory is there. See http://viralpatel.net/blogs/getting-jvm-heap-size-used-memory-total-memory-using-java-runtime/ to determine how much meory is in use and free memory.

To have best utilization it should be both i.e  64 bit os and 64 bit bit vm

On 32-bit editions of Windows, applications have 4 gigabyte (GB) of virtual address space available. The virtual address space is divided so that 2-GB is available to the application and the other 2-GB is available only to the system.See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa366521

so make sure you have enough memory(whatever you are mentioning against params xms and xmx) with the program i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's about the same problem with slight difference in question..

[Eclipse memory allocation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769874/eclipse-memory-allocation-problem/20186675#20186675)

As you can see Java Runtime Environment are set in Java Control Panel. Try to add Runtime parameter e.g `-Xmx3072m` in Runtime Parameter's column.

Or perhaps you could check this article out..

[How to Increase Java Memory in Windows 7](http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7)

Hope it's help solving the problem...

Regards,
Ivan